# Retrieve the 4th div tag inside the first row of a multirow div?

Tags: css, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

Here is the html I am working with. I want to write a css selector for the Item with text "DESIRED ELEMENT":

```
 <div class="TopDiv">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                     <strong>Text1</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">Text2</div>
                <div class="span2">
                     <strong>Text3</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">DESIRED ELEMENT</div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                     <strong>Text4</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">Text5</div>
                <div class="span2">
                     <strong>Text6</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                     <div>Text7</div>
                     <div>Text8</div>
                     <div>Text9</div>
                     <div>Text10</div>
                     <div>Text11</div>
                     <div>Text12</div>
                     <div>Text13</div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I am having a lot of trouble getting to the div that that I want because I don't completely understand the `nth-child of type` this or that or getting a child of a child.

I just want something that is nice and short that will retrieve the 4th div tag child of the first row after container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector depends on if that is the order your elements are always in?

Anyway, you could use:

```
.row:first-child > .span3:last-child
```

This will select the last element with the class `.span3` which is a child of the first `.row`.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDCd3/)

If you want to support `last-child` in IE8 and before, there is always [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/).

---

One selector that should work in IE7/IE8 could be `.row:first-child > .span3 ~ div.span3`.

Only use this though if there are **exactly** two elements inside a row with the `.span3` class.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDCd3/1/)

---

If it's not the last, but always the fourth, use `.row:first-child > div:nth-child(4)`.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDCd3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

> the 4th div tag child of the first row after container.

The css translation of that will be:

after container

```
.container >
```

of the first row

```
.row:first-child >
```

the 4th div tag child

```
div:nth-child(4)
```

so in one line:

```
.container > .row:first-child > div:nth-child(4)
```

find the container class and in childs find the first row class and inside find the 4th div tag.